# udp connection over wifi android

Tags: android, udp, wifi

i'm stuck at creating UDP connection between android phone(2.3) and my PC over wifi.

I know how to create a UDP connection in local server. My problem is do android support adhock network because whenever i try searching for my PC's wifi directly , it doesn't show it , hence i have to first create a virtual hotspot over my PC and then connect my phone to it .

After this , i simply try sending data packets from my phone to server running on my PC.

```
public class WifitestActivity extends Activity {
    WifiManager w;
    TextView status;
    InetAddress server_ip;
    int server_port = 9876;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);

    w = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    if (!w.isWifiEnabled()) {
        status.setText("switching ON wifi ");
        w.setWifiEnabled(true);
    } else {
        status.setText("Its already ON ");

    }

    int x;
    WifiInfo info = w.getConnectionInfo();
    status.append("\n\nWiFi Status: " + info.toString());

    x = info.getIpAddress();
    String str = info.getMacAddress();

    status.append("\n\nmac address===" + str + "  ,ip===" + x);

    try {
        server_ip = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.181.1"); // ip of my server.How to dynamically update it
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        status.append("Error at fetching inetAddress");
    }

    DatagramSocket s = new DatagramSocket(server_port, server_ip);
    // **ERROR AT PREVIOUS LINE, I HAD TO FORCE STOP MY APP EVERTIME I RUN
    // MY CODE**
    String str = "TEST MESSAGE !!!";
    byte b1[];
    b1 = new byte[100];
    b1 = str.getBytes();
    DatagramPacket p1 = new DatagramPacket(b1, b1.length, server_ip,
            server_port);
}
```

}

Server code running on my PC :

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.net.*;
    class server2
    {
        static InetAddress clientip;
        static int clientport;
        static DatagramPacket p3;

        public static void main(String args[])throws Exception
        {

        DatagramSocket s = new DatagramSocket(9876);

        byte b1[],b2[];
        b1=new byte[100];
        b2=new byte[100];

        DatagramPacket p1 = new DatagramPacket(b1,b1.length);
        s.receive(p1);

        b1=p1.getData();
        String str = new String( b1);

        clientport = p1.getPort();  //packet mein save hota hai 
        clientip=p1.getAddress();

        System.out.println("RECIEVED FROM CLIENT IP ="+clientip+" port="+clientport+" data="+str);
        }

}
```

There is an error at client code (WifiTestActivity) and my app crashes whenever i try running it on my phone . Plzz help me out !

Comment: What is your logcat output? You sould post the StackTrace too.

Comment: can you guide me to some resources, i have to implment same sort of system...

Comment: 1- Make either of your phone or PC as hotspot(server) and connect the other to it.
2- Use the code above
3- Keep your server running.
3- Specify permissions in Manifest

Comment: @Infinity tnx for your time

Answer (score 0):

You need the [Internet Permission](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INTERNET). Add this to your manifest:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`